# tapestry4: Access visit object from IEngineService implementation

Tags: java, tapestry

what is the **best** way to get a reference to the current session's visit object from an implementation of IEngineService?

on my pages/components i access it via `@InjectState("visit") public abstract Visit getVisit()`.

Can i inject it into my EngineService via hivemodule.xml or access it via the RequestCycle?

As usual with tapestry, the [documentation mentions nothing...](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/usersguide/state.html#Accessing%20Application%20State%20Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

```
<service-point id="MyService" interface="pkg.MyService">
    <invoke-factory>
        <construct class="pkg.MyService">
            <set-object property="linkFactory" value="infrastructure:linkFactory" />
            <set-service property="appStateMgr" service-id="tapestry.state.ApplicationStateManager"/>
        </construct>
    </invoke-factory>
</service-point>
```

and once it's injected:

```
(Visit) appStateMgr.get("visit")
```